# add primarykey with autoincrement in mysql

Tags: mysql, primary-key, auto-increment, alter-table

how to set particular column  as primary key with auto increment in mysql.am using alter statement . but am getting error when i excecute the alter statement in mysql.

```
alter statement
---------------

 ALTER TABLE tbl_travelplan add COLUMN TRREQNO id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: @sashikant Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, ADD PRIMARY KEY (id)' at line 1

Comment: Ask for help but don't provide the error, errors are usually not needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the real problem is the space between TRREQNO and id in your query.
Try the query i have placed below:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_travelplan add TRREQNO_id INT(11) NOT NULL primary KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Comment: You mean to say, you are facing the same issue with error that you have mentioned in your above comment?

Answer (score 3):

You need to DROP THE PRIMARY KEY FIRST:
Try this ::

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_travelplan add TRREQNO_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, DROP PRIMARY KEY,PRIMARY KEY;    

ALTER TABLE tbl_travelplan add TRREQNO_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

Comment: Uhm, wtf? Why is this answer accepted, and why did it get upvotes? It shouldn't even work?

Answer (score 0):

You have to drop the existing index first using

```
DROP_INDEX [your_existing_index] ON tbl_travelplan
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query

```
alter table tbl_travelplan 
    add TRREQNO_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMET PRIMARY KEY
```

Answer (score -1):

I think in that table already having primary key. So only these kind of error came.
Please remove the primary key and run your query.

Please run this query

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` add TRREQNO id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT DROP PRIMARY KEY ,
ADD PRIMARY KEY ( `id` )
```